# How can I separate networks so users can only see computers in their own department?

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch

With 5 different departments, I want people to see and ping only one's department computers.

60 computers are connected in LAN environment through various switches, routers and one Cisco Managed Switch. Each department has different IP series. In this scenario one can ping and see computers of other department in Network Discovery, which I want to stop.

Comment: Can you give more info on the network? Is it directory network or not? Do all users connect to the Internet trough the same gateway or every department has it's own connection? Do you have onsite mail servers? There are too many variables to simply say - use VLANs. If you have common servers and/or Internet connection you will have to route between VLANs to enable everyone to get their mail, connect to ERP, surveillance or whatever. IF you could graph out your network we might be able to give a much better recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Give each department a VLAN and (possibly) don't route between VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

Setup ACL on each VLAN to deny access to all other 4 VLANs (IP subnets) and allow others.